# Add Floating button in auto-generated map activity from Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Dears,

I'd like to add a Floating button to the Map Layout auto-generated by Android studio.
I tried multiple solutions but none of them make the button appearing: it seems it's always showing behind the fragment.

How can I solve this issue?
I'd like to add the classic circle floating button on bottom right over the map, without creating a bottom-bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/moveCameraButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Ideas?
That should be the final result
[image: Final result]

Comment: You're using Linearlayout as Parent Layout,, Linearlayout does not overlap views. Try it with Relativelayout

Comment: Answer back, I'll vote it as a solution

Comment: posted the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Linearlayout as Parent Layout,, Linearlayout does not overlap views. Try it with Relativelayout